# Access project related data from Gradle command

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I need project related data like project name,app version and its main module from gradle based android project. I have tried various tasks like project,properties but none of it giving me specific information i need.

Is there a way to find version code,app name and main android module using gradle in command line?

Comment: Are you looking for a task that will print version code and app name when run from the command line? Also, what do you mean by 'main android module' ?

Comment: I want it without editing/updating source code.

Comment: do you and to SET or GET the data from gradle command line ?

Comment: I am setting up jenkins job for sonar code analysis. I am using sonar runner to run analysis usin bash command in which i need to set project name and main module's name which we want to scan. So to make it generic without taking any input from user, I need to take it from source code itself.

Answer (score 2):

Using "BuildConfig" global variable you will get

boolean DEBUG

String APPLICATION_ID

String BUILD_TYPE

String FLAVOR

int VERSION_CODE

String VERSION_NAME

eg :- BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID

and if you defined any global data in gradle like

```
debug {

            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", '"http://172.16.1.175:8080/api/"'
            debuggable true
        }
```

you will get this details also

BuildConfig.BASE_URL

Answer (score 1):

You can probably write your own custom gradle task for doing that. Add this code snippet in your app build.gradle, where you define your android plugin and run it from console. You can format output like you need it and use other data from build script.

`task hello<<{
    println("versionCode = ${android.defaultConfig.versionCode}")
    println("applicationId = ${android.defaultConfig.applicationId}")
    println("minSDK = ${android.defaultConfig.minSdkVersion}")
}`

Answer (score 0):

you can use resValue for that to get value

**Gradle**

```
 defaultConfig {
            //other config
            resValue "String","versionCode","1"

        }
```

your class

```
context.getString(R.string.versionCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it suits, you can create one common init gradle file, which you run from command line, so it is not a source code manipulation, where you print out all necessary data. But gradle output is dirty.

This is snippet of init.gradle which is in `/Users/username`

```
allprojects{
    afterEvaluate({//listen for project evaluation
        println(project.name)//it is supposed to be 2 projects "ProjName" and "app"
        if(project.name.equalsIgnoreCase("app")){//or any other condtion to check if it is inner android project
            project.task("getVersion",{
                println("versionCode = ${android.defaultConfig.versionCode}")
            })
        }
    });
}
```

you start this script like `./gradlew --I /Users/username/init.gradle`
This is what I have as an output

```
music
app
versionCode = 1
:help

Welcome to Gradle 2.4.

To run a build, run gradlew <task> ...

To see a list of available tasks, run gradlew tasks

To see a list of command-line options, run gradlew --help

To see more detail about a task, run gradlew help --task <task>

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 6.929 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon:     http://gradle.org/docs/2.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
```

So this is what could be done, another available option is to parse build.gradle file or manifest.xml in bash, or write own console utility that will do it with a cleaner output.
I hope I helped.